# Different MYSQL performances on test/prod system

Tags: mysql, performance, docker

I have been met with a very bizzare performance issue and wanted to see if anyone here would have any input on the problem.

To put it simply, we have hugely different query performances on our test and production server.

Hardware configurations are similar and are the following (both are VMs):

```
Machine     CPU      RAM    Storage
Production  8xCore   16GB   550GB
Test        2xCore   16GB   240GB
```

Neither disk usage is close to 90% (possible fragmentation issues to filled disk space). CPUs are the same:

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6132 CPU @ 2.60GHz
```

I have been running tests on both machines to try and track the root of problem, and all i have so far is pointing to IO (mostly read) issues. I could be (and probably am) wrong here and that's why i wanted to get your input.
Problem here is that i do not have access to the hardware of said VMs so that is a little constraining.

Tests i have done were all using the same MYSQL Docker image (version 5.7.21), running on completely same database (same dump file was loaded, difference was 112 KBs) and using same mysql configuration:

```
[mysqld]

query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_limit = 256K

join_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M

innodb_log_file_size = 2047M

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
max_allowed_packet=1G

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

#log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

server-id        = 1
sql_mode=
group_concat_max_len=15000


innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64
```

I have pastebined full configuration so i can share it if needed (`show variables;`)
I have run some more complex procedures involving combination of SELECTs and DELETEs, but performance outliners can be seen even on simple query such as `SELECT COUNT(*);`

Before each test, mysql server was restarted as to empty the buffer pool.
Test machine:

```
mysql> select COUNT(ID_) FROM ACT_HI_DETAIL;
+------------+
| COUNT(ID_) |
+------------+
|    9411231 |
+------------+
1 row in set (1 min 20.91 sec)
```

IOStat output during query execution
[image: IOStat output during query execution]

Prod machine:

```
mysql> select COUNT(ID_) FROM ACT_HI_DETAIL;
+------------+
| COUNT(ID_) |
+------------+
|    9411231 |
+------------+
1 row in set (8 min 48.95 sec)
```

IOStat output during query execution (last rows)
[image: IOStat output during query execution]

This performance difference is apparent over all use cases, especially during application load. Differences in write speed are of lesser factor, but still present.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The [rMB/s](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/iostat.htm) (Megabytes read per second) column appears to have significant differences with Prod being lower than Test - what disks are you using in your servers - are the HDDs the same? Manufacturer? I can see from the question that the size is different - could this be a factor?

Comment: This is sort of another part of the problem, since we do not have access to the hardware, instead the client does the hosting of VMs. We have posed this very same question and got the answer that the DateStores that the VMs use have disks of same performances. Regarding the size, we requested creation of new temp VM on the same hypervisor as prod machine (but with the same resources as the test machine) and its performances were as slow as the production VM (storage being the same size as test) so i do not think storage size is the issue.

Comment: Hmmm.... `got the answer that the DateStores that the VMs use have disks of same performances.`. Theoretical answers are not worth the paper that they're printed on! ;-) If I were you I would investigate the disks - it's all very well **saying** that the performance is the same - you have a problem and my instinct tells me that it's disk related - maybe I'm wrong, but I would urge you to look in that direction! p.s. welcome to the forum! ;-)

Comment: Thanks, always feels a lil' weird goin from lurker to poster, good weird tho :D. Honestly, i feel the same, but i wanted to do everything in my power to test and try things on our end, as to avoid "passing the blame torch", if the problem was truly on our side. But at this point, i am out of ideas as to what to do and try software-wise anymore, except pursue the investigation of different storage devices or some other hardware related issues.

Comment: Get them to explain the large, and consistently different, difference in `await`.

Comment: Will do Rick. Thank you both! Will get back with updated info, hopefully soon.

Comment: Additional information request FROM prod AND test, please. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: Please post TEXT results from PROD and TEST of SHOW CREATE TABLE act_hi_detail;